# Problem installing parallels tools

Tags: installation

I am a new user of Ubuntu. I installed 12.04 on my MBP. But I cannot install Parallels tools. I tried to follow every process that I found here. 
Can anyone please help me?
Nayan

Comment: Please add more information to your question, specifically what error you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

You have to have user root's privileges to install the Parallels Tools. i.e. use sudo.

After I upgraded to Parallels 7 Desktop on my Mac I needed to install the Parallels Tools.

First of all, on the Mac, `Parallels Desktop >> Virtual Machine >> (Re)Install Parallels Tools` will cause the Parallels Tools virtual install disk to be mounted at `/media/Parallels\ Tools/` so ...

Here's what I did in an Ubuntu Terminal session:

```
parallels@ubuntu:~$ cd /media/Parallels\ Tools/  
parallels@ubuntu:~$ sudo ./install # enter your password when asked
```

and followed the on-screen instructions. Some of the steps take some time, but, when successful, you see a congrats message.

Comment: If, after upgrading Ubuntu to 12.04 you get an error at reboot complaining that Ubuntu cannot mount /media/psf, choose to skip mounting psf; then invoke the install script as in the answer above,, but choose to **remove** Parallels Tools. Then, when Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop reboots correctly, (re)-install Parallels Tools.

Comment: The Parallels Troubleshooting help also suggests turning off 3D Acceleration in the Parallels Desktop >> Virtual Machine >> Hardware settings.

Comment: @Nayan Don't forget to accept this as the correct answer if it helped; you can do that by clicking the image of an outlined tick to the left of the answer :)

Answer (score -2):

you may have suspicion that it may have updated you, especially if you use an older version, as I do. You can check by going into the terminal, and entering

cat /etc/lsb-release

The result should be something similar to mine, which looks like this:

DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu

DISTRIB_RELEASE=6.10

DISTRIB_CODENAME=edgy

DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 6.10"